# How to add red background fill to cells with false value in columns of excel using python

Tags: python, excel, comparison

I have an excel file. It has columns like C_ID,A_ID, ID_Comparison,C_Title,A_Title,Title_Comparisom and so on. The comparison columns have true or false based on comparing the columns.I want to add a background fill for cells of comparison columns if the value is false. I have many sheets in one excel file and in one sheet I have columns like above.i want to iterate over each sheet for each sheet I need to look over columns to filter comparison columns and do the operation and produce a new Excel file.

```
Import pandas as pd

from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

with pd.ExcelFile(input file) as xls:


Dfs = {sheet_name: xls.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names}

For sheet_name,  df in dfs.items():

 for col in df.filter(regex='_Comparison').columns:

    df[col] = df[col].map({True: "True", False: "False"})

    with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:

        # Export DataFrame content

        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

        # Set background colors depending on cell values

        sheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

        column_letter = get_column_letter(sheet[f'{col}1'].column)

        for cell, in sheet[f'{column_letter}2:{column_letter}{len(df) + 1}']:

            value = df[col].iloc[cell.row - 2] # value is "True" or "False"

            cell.fill = PatternFill("solid", start_color=("5cb800" if value == "True" else 'ff2800'))
```

This code is overwriting the output file everytime it loops over comparison columns. I want to get the output file just as input file. All the columns on the same order just that the comparison columns will have a red bg fill for false values.